# Firefox No-Script ABE block oauth over github.com on intranet site

Tags: firefox, github, noscript

This is the ABE SYSTEM rule:

```
Site 172.17.200.197:81
Accept from .github.com
Accept from SELF
#Accept ALL
Deny
```

OAuth works if I uncomment Accept ALL.

If not, I get an error.

JavaScript Console:

```
[ABE] < 172.17.200.197:81> Deny on {GET http://172.17.200.197:81/login?code=42c2ce82d07c40e4d355&state=0.1208564521232749 <<< https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=00d35bdbef7a7f1aea54&scope=read%3Aorg&state=0.1208564521232749&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F172.17.200.197%3A81%2Flogin, http://172.17.200.197:81/login - 6}
SYSTEM rule:
Site 172.17.200.197:81
Accept from .github.com
Accept from SELF
Deny
```

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're describing here -- but, as of right now, Github is down worldwide. Are you sure that isn't the problem? :)

Comment: It worked if I uncomment #Accept ALL
 So generally it works. And if not works it make specific ABE block message.

Comment: Right now it still work (with Accept ALL cheat ). But github.com respond slowly.